# Grails run-app causes error generating web.xml file and bootstrap.groovy not included in war file

Tags: maven, grails, intellij-idea

I am working on an maven application. When I run it from IntelliJ, it successfully launches my application. But bootstrap.groovy file is not being read. I have created a new username to be added to DB in bootstrap and it should allow me to login to the application using that username for the first time. This is not getting invoked during the start of the program. What settings should I do to include bootstrap.groovy.

The same happens when I create a war file and deploy it in the test server. Bootstrap.grrovy is not read. To create the war file, I use mvn package in command line.

My other question with the same application is that when I do grails run-app, I get the following error: Error generating web.xml file.

What is that I am missing? Please let me know.

Comment: Are you sure your spelling of `Bootstrap.groovy` is correct? You've spelt it wrong twice in the question...

Answer (score 1):

Well, I fixed the issue. The web.xml was created when I changed the grails dependent jar. I was using 2.3.4 in my application and my jar was incompatible as I had 2.4.3 version of the jar. Now my program is up and running! Hope this helps someone who is facing the same problem.